# Implement TreeMap: why can't I print my own defined case class?

Tags: scala, treemap, case-class

I'm new to Scala.

I'm trying to implement `TreeMap` using Binary Search Tree.

I found that I can print a non-empty `TreeMap` but the code won't compile if
I try to print `Empty()` (which is a case class defined by me)

The error message is:

> [error] test.scala:33:16: type mismatch;
>
> [error]  found   : Nothing <:< Nothing
>
> [error]  required: K => Ordered[K]
>
> [error]   println(Empty())
>
> [error]                ^
>
> [error] one error found
>
> [error] (test:compileIncremental) Compilation failed

My source code:

```
val tm:TreeMap[Int, String] = Node(Empty(), Empty(), 4, "ddd")
println(tm) // prints "4->ddd"
//println(Empty()) //This won't compile


abstract class TreeMap[K <% Ordered[K], +V] extends AbstractMap[K, V] {

//Implementation omitted.
    override def +[V1 >: V](key: (K, V1)): TreeMap[K, V1] = ......

    override def -(key: K): TreeMap[K, V] = ......

    override def get(key: K): Option[V] = ......

    override def iterator: Iterator[(K, V)] = ......
}

case class Empty[K <% Ordered[K]]() extends TreeMap[K, Nothing]
case class Node[K <% Ordered[K], +V](left: TreeMap[K, V], 
     right: TreeMap[K, V], key: K, value: V) extends TreeMap[K, V]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting.

It is clear, that problem in type resolution for `Empty()` call. As you probably know, `[A <% Ordered[A]]` is equivalent to `[A](implicit ev: A => Ordered[A])` (and view bound is deprecated by the way). So I rewrote you approach a bit different (with partial implementation of missing methods):

```
import scala.collection.AbstractMap

abstract class TreeMap[K, +V](implicit ev: K => Ordered[K])
  extends AbstractMap[K, V] {
  //Implementation omitted.
  override def +[V1 >: V](key: (K, V1)): TreeMap[K, V1] = this
  override def -(key: K): TreeMap[K, V] = this
  override def get(key: K): Option[V]
  override def iterator: Iterator[(K, V)]
}


case class Node[K, +V](left: TreeMap[K, V],
                       right: TreeMap[K, V],
                       key: K,
                       value: V)(implicit ev: K => Ordered[K]) 
  extends TreeMap[K, V] {
  override def get(key: K): Option[V] =
    if (key == this.key) Some(value)
    else None

  override def iterator: Iterator[(K, V)] =
    Iterator((key, value))
}

case class Empty[K](implicit ev: K => Ordered[K])
  extends TreeMap[K, Nothing] {
  override def get(key: K): Option[Nothing] = None
  override def iterator: Iterator[(K, Nothing)] = Iterator.empty
}

val tm: TreeMap[Int, String] =
  Node(Empty(), Empty(), 4, "ddd")
val tm2: TreeMap[Int, String] = Empty()

println(tm) // prints Map("4->ddd")
println(tm2) // prints Map()
println(Empty[Nothing]()) //prints Map()
//println(Empty()) //This won't compile
```

As you can see even call `Empty[Nothing]()` works. I would expect that `Empty()` should work similar way, but no. To understand why, I used `scalac` options `-Xprint:typer -Ydebug -Xprint-types -Ytyper-debug` to see the difference for codes:

```
object SomeClass extends App {
  case class Something3[T](implicit ev: T => Ordered[T])

  Something3()
}
```

and

```
object SomeClass extends App {
  case class Something3[T](implicit ev: T => Ordered[T])

  Something3[Nothing]()
}
```

Looks like compiler while resolving type first try to resolve implicit parameter (which is `T => Ordered[T]` instead of `Nothing => Ordered[Nothing]` and got `Nothing => Nothing`), and than type `T`, and after that you see error (it is my understanding of what I see comparing output, without deep knowledge in compiler terms).

I checked implementation of `scala.collections.immutable.TreeMap`, and they implemented it with delegate under the hood.

As I can see that you cannot avoid using `Key` type for `Empty`, if you want to go with `AbstractMap` as parent. And change variance for `K` is not possible as well. I suppose that as soon as it is compile-time error, you can leave it as is (if it is the only problem in your implementation), with note in comment that stand-alone `Empty` should be explicitly typed for `Key` class (either with meaningful class or `Nothing`).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have added a type param and a view bound to `Empty`, but you have not provided a compatible type (nor can one be inferred) at the line

```
println(Empty())
```

A compatible type can be inferred at the previous line:

```
 Node(Empty(), Empty(), 4, "ddd")
```

I think the correct fix is to make the key type for `Empty()` be fixed at `Nothing` and to make `TreeMap` covariant in the key type, i.e.

```
abstract class TreeMap[+K <% Ordered[K], +V] ...

case class Empty() extends TreeMap[Nothing, Nothing]
```

You could also make `Empty` a case object, rather than a class, since it is constant:

```
case object Empty extends TreeMap[Nothing, Nothing]
```

Comment: Converting `Empty` to object is not possible. Because `K` is invariant in AbstractMap parent